# The app did not appear in the Android Auto screen when we attempted to test functionality

Tags: android, google-play, android-auto, mediabrowserservice, android-automotive

I have a audio player app on playstore and wanted to add support for AndroidAuto.
After making the required changes, when I uploaded my new apk to playstore it got rejected and received the following email from Play

When they say app did not appear on the screen, what does it mean?
I have all the required entries in manifest, made my service browsable. I do not understand what is missing.

I am able to test the app on real android device and it's functioning as it should.

---------- Email from google play ----------

*App status*: Your app has not been accepted into Android Auto, and the update is not live on Google Play.

*Eligibility issues by APK version:*
**The app did not appear in the Auto screen when we attempted to test functionality**.

To be considered for Android Auto:

- Make the necessary changes to your app.
- Increment the version number of the upgraded APK.
- Submit your app for another review.

Or, if you’d like to exclude your app from Android Auto:

- Remove the Android Auto manifest entry from your APK code.
- Sign in to your Play Console and upload the new APK.
- Click Submit update.

For more details on how an app can qualify for Android Auto, you can review the the Android Auto App Quality Guidelines.

If you feel we have made this determination in error, please submit additional information to our team and we’ll review your app again.

Thanks for supporting Google Play,

The Google Play Team

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions regarding support queries about the Google Play Console or other related products should be asked in the relevant support forums.

Comment: I do not feel that this is a support related query.But rather need help in identifying the missing ingredient for Android Auto

Comment: I have also seen couple of questions with similar issues, being rejected for android-auto and their question is not removed.

Comment: You say that your app functioned correctly on a real Android device. Does that mean you ran the Android Auto app and your app showed up in media menu? If it does not show up there, then it won't show up on a car screen, either.

Comment: Yes, it did show up in Android Auto app on couple of Android devices and we were able to play media items from it.

Comment: Did someone resolve this problem?

Comment: Nope, ultimately I reverted the code and squashed all android-auto related changes and pushed new apk so that normal android app updates are pushed and I am not blocked. I tried to contact Play Support but kept receiving robot response in mail which was not helpful

Comment: We use the same code to create different apps depending on flavor. Even if they share the same code, some pass the review, and others are rejected. One of two options: The ones that passed the review were incorrectly tested, or the other ones were rejected by a false positive.